# i get 'SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong version number' Error

Tags: python, ssl, twisted

when i send post request to daemon server using curl it shows below.

> [Faulure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class
> 'twisted.web._newClient.ResponseNeverReceived'>:
> [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines',
> 'ssl_get_record', 'wrong version number')]>]

```
def creatorForNetloc(self, hostname, port):
        with open(self.ssl_pem_file_path) as pem_file:
            with open(self.ssl_key_file_path) as key_file:
                cert = ssl.PrivateCertificate.loadPEM(pem_file.read() + key_file.read())
        return CertificateOptions(
            cert.privateKey.original,
            cert.original,
            requireCertificate=False,
            verify=False)
```

i use openssl 1.0.2(centos7.9), pyopenssl 19.1.0 and use tls1.2

when i use openssl check it returns verify code 21 is this could be the problem?

how do i do?

Comment: Too few context given. But in general: there is no way for a server to disable certificate validation in the client (i.e. `-k`). Otherwise a man in the middle attacker could just force clients to not validate the certificate to mount a successful attack. It's like presenting a fake identification to the police but forcing the policy to not check the validity of the identification.

Comment: i checked the version and was 'OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017'
this could cause problem?

Comment: Please add a self-contained example to your question.